# Dynamically changing angular-tooltips content on form errors

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, tooltip

I am trying to integrate angular-tooltips with input form. I want to change tooltip text on `registrationForm.email.$error` object change.

HTML:

```
<input tooltips tooltip-html="{{ emailToolTip }}" tooltip-show-trigger="focus" tooltip-hide-trigger="blur" tooltip-side="right"/>
<div>{{emailToolTip}}</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.emailToolTip = 'Initial tooltip';
$scope.$watch('registrationForm.email.$error', function (newVal) {
  $scope.emailToolTip = 'Updated tooltip';
}}, true);
```

above code changes `<div>` value but it doesn't change `<input>`'s 'tooltip-html' attribute value. Am I missing anything or is it a bug?

I am using this angular-tooltips library
https://github.com/720kb/angular-tooltips

Comment: do you have any idea how we can use `tooltip-show-trigger` with custom events or something similar. I want to show tooltip at page load but `onload`, `load`, `onready` etc are not working. Any idea, how we can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use

`tooltip-title="{{ emailToolTip }}"`

instead of

`tooltip-html="{{ emailToolTip }}"`

Comment: Great! it works, but I was wondering why html doesn't work. I want to add some html content in it.

Comment: If it solved your problem you can accept this solution. thanks

Comment: Its added as a feature in this library now https://github.com/720kb/angular-tooltips/issues/78

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your link I'd guess you should look to : "Tooltip view controller"
in order to have a dynamic content